# How does a host machine actually execute instructions of a virtual machine?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine

How does a Host machine really "host" a virtual machine? How is it given a kernel of its own? Are instructions and syscalls of a virtual machine translated into machine language and passed to the host? Is it passed down as a byte stream? Is there an interpreter which converts syscalls from the virtual operating system to the host operating system?

The more I think about Virtual Machines the more confusing it gets.

Answers to any of these would be great!

Comment: I'd ask this on Quora, or just google it first.

Comment: This is really the definition of 'too broad'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the confusion is that the term 'virtual machine' has been co-opted to describe different things, so each requires a different answer.  For example, the 'Java Virtual Machine (JVM)' is really just a program built to interpret a bytecode instruction set custom-built to support Java (though there is more to it than that, of course), so any attempt to answer your question in that context would be to explain how an interpreter works.  What I am going to do is go back to *the original meaning of 'virtual machine'* and explain that.  *(note: I have no idea how much of what I am about to describe applies for modern VMs)*

The term *virtual machine* originally described a multi-programming operating-system technique used to provide each of a large number of users their own complete computing environment.  By 'complete' I mean this: Normally each user is given a 'space' for running programs, but each program can reach outside of its space only via a fixed, common operating system; in this technique, each user would be given a 'space' which *appears* to be an *entire bare machine*, so in particular each user could run *their own multi-tasking operating system* if they so chose.

The way this was achieved depended on two features of the hardware: (1) Programs could be run in one of two modes - *user mode* or *system mode*; (2) Some of the instructions are *privileged* (reserved for the OS), and may only be used in system mode - otherwise the machine 'traps' and tries to execute an illegal-instruction handler routine.  This was exploited by having the base OS implement each user's space as a *simulation of the same hardware*, with simulated user-mode and simulated system-mode, etc.  **All of the user's code was always run in actual user-mode**, regardless of the simulated mode.  That means each instruction's execution was simulated *by the actual hardware itself*, with no interpretive overhead.  The privileged instructions were an exception: They would always 'trap' to the actual operating system, which would handle the interrupt according to the user's simulated mode. If the user's 'machine' was in simulated user-mode, the actual operating system would simulate the hardware interrupt, adjusting the simulated machine state and transferring control to the instruction handler routine -in the simulation- (i.e in the user's space); if the user's 'machine' was in simulated system-mode, the actual operating system would *emulate the privileged instruction*, changing the user's 'machine state' accordingly.